Bounded Approximate Identity Reference
I'm aware of the following result and its proof:
Let $A,B$ be Banach algebras and $A$ have a bounded approximate identity. If there exists $\theta:A\to B$ a continuous algebra homomorphism with dense range, then $B$ also has a bounded approximate identity.
Where can I find a published version of this to use as a citation?

The result is quite easy to prove, two or three lines probably. If you don’t find this explicitly in the literature, maybe you can just write down a proof in the preliminaries section or something?

@DavidGao It’s not that we use this in a super major way, we have a sentence that crams together three hereditary results together. We use these later in quick corollaries to our main theorem, and the other two results already have citations. So it would be nice to just round out the trio!

Ah, I understand that. I was just making a suggestion in case no references could be found, is all. I’ve myself encountered this kind of situations where I needed to use some easily provable, well-known results but couldn’t find a reference.

I would check in Banach Algebras and Automatic Continuity by H. Garth Dales.

I believe I already checked in there, that mentions other hereditary properties with proof but not this specific one (to my knowledge at least!)
